# Why use Circuit Breaker and Bulkhead when working with Spring Reactor?

Tags: project-reactor, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

Please help me find reasons why Circuit breaker and Bulkhead patterns are useful in a Spring Reactor application.

Since operations will be non-blocking in Reactor and those two patterns aim at saving potential hit to resources (mostly threads), in what cases can I benefit the patterns in my Spring Reactor app. The only thing I see at this point is if the requests are such a tremendously huge amount that keeping them in memory, while waiting for a timeout (instead of Circuit Breaker being up and falling back) we run OOM.

Comment: Bulkheads provide guard rails against overflowing Memory due to creation of unlimited threads. I also agree with this thought that it is not needed in a non-blocking IO

Answer (score 1):

Beside protecting your own application, these patterns also help you protect external services (REST API, database, etc): in case of increased latency and/or error rate, you give them room to recover. Failing fast in your application is also beneficial as you don't make your end-users wait too long for an error.

Resilience4j provides dedicated [Reactor support](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/examples-1) for these patterns in place of the deprecated Hystrix library.

Comment: Protecting external service is none of my concern in my case and I guess the external service should take care of itself. Apart from that, failing fast is indeed beneficial, thanks for you answer - looking forward to more ideas, though