# Do we need Hystrix if we use WebFlux?

Tags: spring-webflux, hystrix

As per my understanding, with reactive programming (Web Flux), the threads do not need to wait for the response and they can serve other requests.

This is exactly the problem that Hystrix addresses as well. I mean, if we make a synchronous call using rest template without Hystrix, we might soon run out of number of available threads if one of the upstream services taking too long to respond.

My question is, if we use WebFlux, do we even need to bother about Hystrix?

There was a similar question on Stack overflow, but the description of the question took a different direction. Also, there is no straight answer to it.

Could you clarify?

Comment: if you are using the circuit breaker/fallback features of hystrix then yes, you still need it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use Circuit Breaker and Bulkhead when working with Spring Reactor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872623/why-use-circuit-breaker-and-bulkhead-when-working-with-spring-reactor)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. It clarifies. Can I conclude that there won't be a resource issue with WebFlux?